# Loading of word Addin in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I have created a project , which creates MS word Addins ,after that i created the set up project of it , but the problem is when i install that setup the word addins are not loaded .
I tried on two to three Computers i cant able  to get the addins in MS word .

Is there some procedure to load that addin dll in Ms Word .

Please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit vague, no errors, etc, just they aren't installed? Not much to go on.

In any case, the first place I start is looking in the registry

hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins

Make sure your addin is registered there and that the MANIFEST key points to a valid manifest file.

If that checks out, load Word and check in the Addins window (File/Options/Addins/Com Addins) that your addin isn't being disabled by word for some reason.